# Creating multiple hubs dynamically using SignalR

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am currently using `SignalR` for chat. I have a form and the user will load a specific order into the form. The scenario is that other `staff members` may search that order number and therefore i want only those people to be in the chat. Currently if you load the site everyone is in a single `hub` called `ChatHub`.

**ChatHub.cs:**

```
public class ChatHub: Hub {
 public void Send(string name, string message) {
  // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
  Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
 }
}
}
```

**Chat.cshtml:**

```
@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append(htmlEncode(name)
                    + ':' + htmlEncode(message) + '\n');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.

            //$('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
<script>
```

**I have tried to add the following:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var chat = jQuery.connection.chat;

    chat.addMessage = function (message, room) {

        if ($('#currentRoom').val() == room) {
            $('#messagesList').append(message);
        }
    };


        chat.send($('#textboxMessage').val(), $('#currentRoom').val());
        $('#textboxMessage').val("");


    $.connection.hub.start();
});
</script>
```

I am trying to work out a way of getting multiple hubs or chat rooms based on a user loading an order.

Comment: Do you have a question? Currently you're just saying what you've done but what you're trying to achieve or what the problem is.

Comment: Yes i am trying to find out of a way to create an order specific chat. So 2 people load an order and only they get to be part of the chat. But if a 3rd person loads it, they are part of it also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put the users into groups according to the opened order id, change the hub and add a method as below:

```
public class ChatHub: Hub {
 public void Send(string name, string message,string orderId) {
  // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
  Clients.Group(orderId).addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
 }

public void JoinOrderGroup(string name,string orderId)
 {
     Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, orderId);
 }
}
```

Then modify your JavaScript to call the `JoinOrderGroup' when the user opens the page.

```
@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
             var orderId = '@Model.Id' //You can change this line to get the orderId from the correct place
             var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append(htmlEncode(name)
                    + ':' + htmlEncode(message) + '\n');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.

            //$('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                  chat.server.joinOrderGroup($('#displayname').val(),orderId);
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
<script>
```

This way, when the page starts and the hub connects, it will send a message to join the group related to the order in the form, and all successive calls to teh send message method will include the order id and it will be propagated to the users in this order only.

Comment: How  would you determine who is in the Group?

Comment: The group is the order number as you indicated in your question, every user has the order screen opened should be able to chat with other users seeing the same order, right?

Comment: Yes, and people who have a different order wont be able to be part of the same chat. Can you update your code that on exit, it removes the person?

Comment: @PriceCheapterton on the Hub side, you are notified when a client connects or disconnect. They provide a ConnectionId which you can use to remove the disconnected user from the Group.

Comment: And I believe each time the user connects will have a separate Id

Comment: @HaithamShaddad Correct, its the browser that creates the unique id not the hub and for each new connection a new id is created.

Comment: I am trying to work with this and it doesnt work correctly. Messages dont actually get sent to the group :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with groups:
https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups